Angular stuck on version 10.2. Won't update to version 11
I'm trying to update angular and the output shows no errors, but it just won't progress past version 10.2
Ran both ng update @angular/cli@11, and ng update @angular/core@11. See output below
ng update
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 29 dependencies.
    We analyzed your package.json, there are some packages to update:

      Name                               Version                  Command to update
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      @angular/cli                       10.2.4 -> 11.2.9         ng update @angular/cli@11
      @angular/core                      10.2.5 -> 11.2.9         ng update @angular/core@11

G:\Users\Darkreaper\Git\VirtualBar\VirtualBar>ng update @angular/cli@11
The installed Angular CLI version is outdated.
Installing a temporary Angular CLI versioned 11.2.19 to perform the update.
Installing packages for tooling via npm.
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 29 dependencies.
Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular-devkit/build-angular @ "0.1102.19" (was "0.1002.4")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/cli @ "11.2.19" (was "10.2.4")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/compiler-cli @ "11.2.14" (was "10.2.5")...
    Updating package.json with dependency karma @ "6.4.3" (was "5.0.5")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/animations @ "11.2.14" (was "10.2.5")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/common @ "11.2.14" (was "10.2.5")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/compiler @ "11.2.14" (was "10.2.5")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/core @ "11.2.14" (was "10.2.5")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/forms @ "11.2.14" (was "10.2.5")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/platform-browser @ "11.2.14" (was "10.2.5")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/platform-browser-dynamic @ "11.2.14" (was "10.2.5")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/router @ "11.2.14" (was "10.2.5")...

G:\Users\Darkreaper\Git\VirtualBar\VirtualBar>ng update @angular/core@11
The installed Angular CLI version is outdated.
Installing a temporary Angular CLI versioned 11.2.19 to perform the update.
Installing packages for tooling via npm.
Installed packages for tooling via npm.
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 29 dependencies.
Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/compiler-cli @ "11.2.14" (was "10.2.5")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/animations @ "11.2.14" (was "10.2.5")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/common @ "11.2.14" (was "10.2.5")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/compiler @ "11.2.14" (was "10.2.5")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/core @ "11.2.14" (was "10.2.5")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/forms @ "11.2.14" (was "10.2.5")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/platform-browser @ "11.2.14" (was "10.2.5")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/platform-browser-dynamic @ "11.2.14" (was "10.2.5")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/router @ "11.2.14" (was "10.2.5")...

But then run ng update again and this is what I get
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 29 dependencies.
    We analyzed your package.json, there are some packages to update:

      Name                               Version                  Command to update
     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      @angular/cli                       10.2.4 -> 11.2.9         ng update @angular/cli@11
      @angular/core                      10.2.5 -> 11.2.9         ng update @angular/core@11

Has anyone ever seen anything like this?
Why is it stuck?
I'm using v20.12.2 of Node

Do your first commands complete successfully? Your terminal stack trace still shows "Updating" as the last line for each command, as if you stopped it before it completed.

I am not sure if it matters, but angular shows to run the commands as one command line command, not two ng update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11

As far as I can tell everything completes. What you see above is the exact output from running ng update, and then the subsequent updates for cli and core since ng update is unable to handle everything apparently
